# C : Initialise reference to variable with double

Tags: c++, syntax, reference

What does the following do:

```
double &number = 12.4;
```

It should assign the reference to variable of type double as 12.4

but isn't a reference to variable an address of a pointer . Why does it work?

```
double & Getsomenumber()
{
    static double number = 12.4;

    double &anotherNumber = number;

    return anotherNumber;}
```

Comment: The function has the problem that it returns a reference to a local object. As soon as the function returns, the value is gone.

Comment: Yeah.....................

Comment: C? With references? No way...

Answer (score 3):

That's illegal syntax, there are no references in C.

If you meant C++, then that is also invalid, you can't bind temporaries to non-`const` references. `const double& number = 12.4` would work.

So "Why does it work?" isn't a valid question - it doesn't, not for C, not for C++.

> but isn't a reference to variable an address of a pointer

No. A reference is just an alias - you're basically referring to the same variable via a different name.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should actually work this way:

```
const double& number = 12.4;
```

Actually you shouldn't be able to create a reference to a const Expression without `const`.